# Как сделать select menu с выбором роли (role_select) (pycord)

Tags: python, discord, pycord

Хочу сделать выдачу роли по кнопке, используя не обычный текст, а роль (role_select), но не знаю как добавить к нему опцию для выдачу роли (options не работает так как это role_select а не обычный). Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать
Код:

```
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.role_select( # the decorator that lets you specify the properties of the select menu
        placeholder = "Выбери роль!", # the placeholder text that will be displayed if nothing is selected
        min_values = 1, # the minimum number of values that must be selected by the users
        max_values = 1, # the maximum number of values that can be selected by the users
    )
    async def select_callback(self, select, interaction): # the function called when the user is done selecting options
        #тут потом сделаю выдачу роли

@bot.command()
async def flavor(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Выбери роль!", view=MyView())
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не много не понял вопрос, но для выдачи роли в discord.py можно использовать

```
await member.add_role(discord.utils.get(role_id))
```

Comment: я про то что есть несколько видов Select Menu, а именно - string_select, user_select, role_select, mentionable_select, channel_select, а option есть только в string`е, и я не знаю как добавить в user_select опцию